# Haskell program with basic CLI parsing, file reading, and decoding file contents into specified types

Tags: haskell

I recently completed the following exercise, but wanted some feedback on how idiomatic etc. my haskell program is. This is from a course which introduces us to file IO before we cover the theory of monads, so my monad-knowledge is still in its infancy. Any feedback much appreciated.

Here's the task:

> In `StudentTeacher.hs`, observe that we have an old version of our `Person` type with the `Student`
> and `Teacher` constructor. Fill in `studentTeacherBasic` so that it will use arguments to determine
> the right type of person. If the arguments contain `-s` or `--student`, read two lines, for name and age,
> and make a student. If there is `-t` or `--teacher`, read two lines for the name and department. If
> there are no arguments, print:
>
> `Please specify the type of person!`
>
> Print the resulting person otherwise.
>
> Fill in studentTeacherAdvanced, which should have the same result as your basic version, but
> read its input differently. Take a file name as the first argument. If it ends in .student, read lines from
> the file assuming they contain a student's information. If it’s .teacher, assume a teacher. Print the
> same failure message in any other case.

Here's my answer:

```hs
module StudentTeacher where

import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import System.IO (openFile, withFile, IOMode(..), hGetLine, hGetContents, Handle, stdin)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Maybe (isNothing)

data Person =
  Student String Int |
  Teacher String String
  deriving (Show)

type PersonDecoder = String -> Maybe Person
type CLIParser = [String] -> Maybe (PersonDecoder, (IO Handle))

studentTeacher :: CLIParser -> IO ()
studentTeacher cliparser = do
  arguments <- getArgs
  maybePerson <- case (cliparser arguments) of
    Nothing -> return Nothing
    Just (decoder, getHandle) -> do
      handle <- getHandle
      decodePersonFromHandle decoder handle
  case maybePerson of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Please specify the type of person"
    Just person -> print person

studentTeacherBasic :: IO ()
studentTeacherBasic = studentTeacher parseArgsFlag

decodePersonFromHandle :: PersonDecoder -> Handle -> IO (Maybe Person)
decodePersonFromHandle decoder handle = do
  line1 <- hGetLine handle
  line2 <- hGetLine handle
  return $ decoder $ line1 ++ "\n" ++ line2

parseArgsFlag :: CLIParser
parseArgsFlag [] = Nothing
parseArgsFlag ("-t":_) = Just (decodeTeacher, wrapStdIn)
parseArgsFlag ("-s":_) = Just (decodeStudent, wrapStdIn)
parseArgsFlag ("--teacher":_) = parseArgsFlag ["-t"]
parseArgsFlag ("--student":_) = parseArgsFlag ["-s"]

wrapStdIn :: IO Handle
wrapStdIn = do
  return stdin

decodeTeacher :: PersonDecoder
decodeTeacher encoded =
  case lines of [] -> Nothing
                [_] -> Nothing
                (name:dept:_) -> Just (Teacher name dept)
  where lines = splitOn "\n" encoded

decodeStudent :: PersonDecoder
decodeStudent encoded =
  case lines of [] -> Nothing
                [_] -> Nothing
                (name:age:_) -> decodeStudentLines name age
  where lines = splitOn "\n" encoded

decodeStudentLines :: String -> String -> Maybe Person
decodeStudentLines name age =
  case decodedAge of Nothing -> Nothing
                     (Just ageInt) -> Just (Student name ageInt)
  where decodedAge = readMaybe age :: Maybe Int

studentTeacherAdvanced :: IO ()
studentTeacherAdvanced = studentTeacher parseArgsSuffix

parseArgsSuffix :: CLIParser
parseArgsSuffix [] = Nothing
parseArgsSuffix (fname:_) =
  if hasSuffix fname "student" then Just (decodeStudent, openFile fname ReadMode)
  else if hasSuffix fname "teacher" then Just (decodeTeacher, openFile fname ReadMode)
  else Nothing

hasSuffix :: String -> String -> Bool
hasSuffix filename suffix = if length components == 0 || length components == 1
  then False
  else last components == suffix
  where
    components = splitOn "." filename
```

Comment: You can use great http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative library for option parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: great work on adding a type signature on every function. Now, let's see how we can improve the code.

### Use interesting case first, others later

When we pattern match in a binding or in a `case` expression, it's often easier to start with the interesting case first and then handle the *Error* cases:

```hs
decodeTeacher :: PersonDecoder
decodeTeacher encoded =
  case lines of (name:dept:_) -> Just (Teacher name dept)
                _             -> Nothing
  where lines = splitOn "\n" encoded

decodeStudent :: PersonDecoder
decodeStudent encoded =
  case lines of (name:age:_) -> decodeStudentLines name age
                _            -> Nothing
  where lines = splitOn "\n" encoded
```

### Check the standard library for already existing functionality

We stay at those functions. The name `lines` is very unfortunate, as there is already a `lines` in the `Prelude`. It's a function with the following signature:

```hs
lines :: String -> [String]
```

With that function, we can get rid of `splitOn`:

```hs
decodeTeacher :: PersonDecoder
decodeTeacher encoded =
  case lines encoded of
    (name:dept:_) -> Just (Teacher name dept)
    _             -> Nothing

decodeStudent :: PersonDecoder
decodeStudent encoded =
  case lines encoded of
    (name:age:_) -> decodeStudentLines name age
    _            -> Nothing
```

### Prefer simpler logic where possible

Next, we have a look at `parseArgsSuffix`:

```hs
parseArgsSuffix :: CLIParser
parseArgsSuffix [] = Nothing
parseArgsSuffix (fname:_) =
  if hasSuffix fname "student" then Just (decodeStudent, openFile fname ReadMode)
  else if hasSuffix fname "teacher" then Just (decodeTeacher, openFile fname ReadMode)
  else Nothing
```

That's a rather long `if` expression. A guard may be easier to read and handle:

```hs
parseArgsSuffix :: CLIParser
parseArgsSuffix [] = Nothing
parseArgsSuffix (fname:_)
  | fname `hasSuffix` "student" = Just (decodeStudent, openFile fname ReadMode)
  | fname `hasSuffix` "teacher" = Just (decodeTeacher, openFile fname ReadMode)
  | otherwise                   = Nothing
```

Note that we should keep the uninteresting case here first, as it improves readability. However, we're repeating ourselves. Something along

```hs
parseArgsSuffix :: CLIParser
parseArgsSuffix [] = Nothing
parseArgsSuffix (fname:_)
  | fname `hasSuffix` "student" = decodeVia decodeStudent 
  | fname `hasSuffix` "teacher" = decodeVia decodeTeacher
  | otherwise                   = Nothing
  where
    decodeVia f = Just (f, openFile fname ReadMode)
```

might reduce the duplication. Now, let's have a look at `hasSuffix`:

```hs
hasSuffix :: String -> String -> Bool
hasSuffix filename suffix = if length components == 0 || length components == 1
  then False
  else last components == suffix
  where
    components = splitOn "." filename
```

Again, `splitOn` is an overkill here. We only want to know if our filename ends with the given extension. The function `isSuffixOf` from `Data.List` handles that fine:

```hs
hasSuffix :: String -> String -> Bool
hasSuffix filename suffix = ('.' : suffix) `isSuffixOf` filename
```

We could probably even remove `hasSuffix` completely that way.

### Make sure that functions are total

`parseArgsFlag` is partial. If we use `parseArgsFlags` on `["whoops!", "-t"]`, then none of the patterns match:

```hs
parseArgsFlag :: CLIParser
parseArgsFlag [] = Nothing
parseArgsFlag ("-t":_) = Just (decodeTeacher, wrapStdIn)
parseArgsFlag ("-s":_) = Just (decodeStudent, wrapStdIn)
parseArgsFlag ("--teacher":_) = parseArgsFlag ["-t"]
parseArgsFlag ("--student":_) = parseArgsFlag ["-s"]
```

If that is intended, then everything is fine. However, if you want to handle those cases, then add a match all pattern:

```hs
parseArgsFlag _               = Nothing
```

I would prefer something like this, by the way:

```hs
parseArgsFlag :: CLIParser
parseArgsFlag args
  | any (`elem` args) ["-t", "--teacher"] = Just (decodeTeacher, wrapStdIn)
  | any (`elem` args) ["-s", "--student"] = Just (decodeStudent, wrapStdIn)
  | otherwise                             = Nothing
```